# cakephp 2.1 black hole in google chrome

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a plugin for cakephp 2.1
all things are working fine on localhost on all browsers

But this plugin is not working on google chrome on server however it is working fine on Firefox

I am getting Error: The requested address '/login' was not found on this server when I submit the form.

For ex.

http://umpremium.ektasoftwares.com/login

Please check this on google chrome as well as Firefox. Can somebody help me out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reach that site in both Google Chrome and Firefox, using `Chrome 18.0.1025.151`

Comment: Can you please login in both browsers?? with admin/123456 
I am using chrome 18.0.1025.142 m

Comment: I can login in both browsers without any problems

Comment: Thanks for taking time on this problem. I deleted the browser cache and now it's working fine